# How to add cache-control header to existing responseHeaderPolicy in aws CDK Cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk, cache-control

I have an AWS CDK Cloudfrount distribution with the default responseHeaderPolicy. I need to add a cache-control directive, but it seems that I have to create from scratch the whole ResponseHeaderPolicy, that includes CORS policies and other configuration that I am fine with the defaults.
Is there a way to edit the default responseHeaderPolicy just to add the cache-control, instead of having to build the whole object?

This is my current configuration:

```js
const cf = new cloudfront.Distribution(this, `cdn-${this.env}`, {
  defaultBehavior: { 
      origin: new origins.S3Origin(this.cdnBucket),
      cachePolicy: custom_policy,
      allowedMethods: cloudfront.AllowedMethods.ALLOW_GET_HEAD_OPTIONS,
      originRequestPolicy: cloudfront.OriginRequestPolicy.CORS_S3_ORIGIN,
      responseHeadersPolicy: cloudfront.ResponseHeadersPolicy.CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS_WITH_PREFLIGHT,
    },
  domainNames: [domain],
  certificate,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible for your CDK code to make incremental modifications to a predefined Response Header Policy like `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS_WITH_PREFLIGHT`.

The reason is that the CDK [policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_cloudfront.ResponseHeadersPolicy.html#static-cors_allow_all_origins_with_preflight) corresponds to a [CloudFront managed policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-managed-response-headers-policies.html).  The CDK only knows the policy ID (`5cc3b908-e619-4b99-88e5-2cf7f45965bd`), which it [passes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cloudfront-distribution-defaultcachebehavior.html#cfn-cloudfront-distribution-defaultcachebehavior-cachepolicyid) to the distribution.  The content of the policy itself is not defined in the CDK.